# dotnet watch run does not open browser

Tags: .net-core

I have a handful of projects, all .Net 7 (core), MVC Projects with razor views (not razor pages).

Most of them open a browser when I run

```
dotnet watch run
```

However, two projects do not. This is the launcsettings.json from one of them - which does NOT launch a browser:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:49994",
      "sslPort": 49999
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ProjectName.Web": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7219;http://localhost:5219",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is one from another project, that DOES launch:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:43618",
      "sslPort": 44365
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      }
    },
    "Another.Proejct.Web": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried changing ports, adding a "launchurl" property, which I found in another SO answer, changing the name of the "Projectname" property etc etc... Nothing seems to fix it.

To be clear - the webserver IS running and I can just open a browser and go to the port specified in launchsettings.json, and it works just fine - but I would really like to fix the missing browser open.

What am I missing?

Comment: the first config is not working just update SSL port 0 and run any endpoint URL

"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:49994",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  }

Comment: @RajatJha That is not the relevant section, as far as I can tell. When it runs, it runs on port  7219, indicating that the section "Projectname.Web" is the relevant one.

Comment: ok got it, so you found the problem?

Comment: @RajatJha No, I did not find a solution. :(

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your actual problem

Comment: Which console output differences do you see when running `dotnet watch run --verbose` on the successful and non-successful projects? Sometimes deleting the `.vs` folder helps.

Comment: Could you try reloading the browser and/or the system?

Comment: what is the project type? looks like a webapp. does your version history show any changes to this file since init?

Comment: Are you maybe missing `ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES` inside `profiles`?